# Getting a property for a cell of a UILabel in its row

Tags: objective-c

I have added a costume row in a `UITableView`, and drag 3 `UILabels` to it .
Also added their outlets and synthesised them.
I gave it an identifier called Cell.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *leftLabel;
```

than when trying to get these labels from cell, i don't have their property in the cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//can't do this :
cell.leftLabel=
cell.rightLabel=
cell does not have their properties . ( they are within the cell in storyboard)
```

Why can't i get their properties ?

Comment: if you don't want subclassing your custom uitableviewcell take a look to this: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/28/customize-a-uitableviewcell-in-cellforrowatindexpath-part-1-no-need-to-subclass-uitableviewcell/

Comment: show the code of UITableViewCell subclass. Also, your cell is is UITableViewCell class, not from your subClass.

Answer (score 0):

Change class name to your custom cell class name not generic one - UITableViewCell:

```
CUSTOMTableViewCell *cell = (CUSTOMTableViewCell*)[self.tableView ...
```

also you have uppercase Cell:

```
Cell.leftLabel=
```

but it should be lowercase:

```
cell.leftLabel=
```

Comment: There is no Cell, its just the identifier name, there is cell .. and i did not get your first row explanation..

Comment: The issue is because you use UITableViewCell class but there is no such property as rightLabel, left, etc. you have to cast this class to the custom class as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Your answer, say something that called CUSTMOTABLEVIEWCELL ,which does not exist, and not clear to other simple people, there is also no similar costume class either .

Comment: By CUSTMOTABLEVIEWCELL I mean your custom class, subclass of UITableViewCell. In your post you said that you have costume row. Replace this with this class name. I believe is the one where you have @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *leftLabel;

Comment: I just don't get what you say. this cell has a costume class field that is empty. and there is a gray text say UITableViewCell. what should i write there ?

Comment: Can you go to the .h file where you declare @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *leftLabel; and post whole line which start with interface keyword ?

Comment: Why is it have to be so hard, i just want to put 3 labels in a cell, thats it . created a cell, drag the labels, and now want to edit them.

Comment: If you do it in storyboard you have to change also class name in Identity inspector to the class you have created (which subclass UITableViewCell) after that you add properties to the .h file in the class, as I believe you have already do) and you connect the label from storyboard to this class. After that you just replace UITableViewCell to your custom cell class in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, as I shown above.

Comment: The view which contains the tableview, has a class of course, called classA. this is where the property goes. what you say is that i have to replace the  CUSTMOTABLEVIEWCELL , with classA ?

Comment: No. Have a look on this tutorial: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) see section: Designing Our Own Prototype Cells. It's the simplest way you can do custom cell. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks it helped, but its completely different from what you suggested, and frankly i did not see even one example on the net with this costume class definition ..

Comment: This is not class name it's my name to replace this text with your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are referring to the Cell but there is no such instance, you are using in your code `cell`.

You will also need your custom table view cell. You can create it by inheriting from UITableViewCell.
You will also need to specify class and reusable identifier in storyboard, and use it instead of `@"Cell"`